# Textbox value in MVC3 using ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textbox, viewbag

Consider a textbox field in a View made using an Html Helper.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.name, new {@value=ViewBag.x});
```

In this case, if in my model I pass some value(not null), then what will be the value of my textbox, the ViewBag.x, or the one I've passed in my model object??

Comment: what happens when you test your code? which value displays?

Comment: are you asking a question? or are you checking others skills?

Comment: Don't know!..Iam testing it right now...but I wanted to know beforehand so I won't have to test it :p

Comment: @HariGillala: Asking a question only

Comment: Testing it takes a lot less time than typing, posting and waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** override the `value` property of a strongly typed helper. Forget about strongly typed helpers if you use `ViewBag`. Once you go that route, you will have to follow it:

```
@Html.TextBox("x")
```

where `x` is something that you have stuffed into the ViewBag in your controller action:

```
ViewBag.x = "foo";
```

Strongly typed helpers work with the model and use the lambda expression passed as first argument to get the value.

So if you want to do things properly throw the `ViewBag` away and use view models and strongly typed helpers:

```
@Htlm.TextBoxFor(model => model.X)
```

Comment: So, you mean the ViewBag property will be used,even if my Model.name is not null, right?

Comment: ViewBag will not be used if you use TextBoxFor. As I said in my answer you cannot override the `value` attribute.